# Creating a GeoPoint complex data type in Facebook Open Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am attempting to create a GeoPoint type to my existing Object. Facebook's documentation here isn't exactly stellar - but what I went ahead and did was create a new property and named it `location`. I made it of type GeoPoint and required.

I then supply the following in my template:

```
  <meta property="my-app:location:latitude" content="<%= @location.lat %>" />
  <meta property="my-app:location:longitude" content="<%= @location.lng %>" />
```

Yet the debugger complains:

```
The parser's result for this metadata did not match the input metadata. Likely, this was caused by the data being ordered in an unexpected way, multiple values being given for a property only expecting a single value, or property values for a given property being mismatched. Here are the input property =>content pairs that were not seen in the parsed result: 'my-app:location:latitude => 40.134537901957735, my-app:location:longitude => -75.00853989318185'
```

How am I supposed to define this GeoPoint and how am I supposed to embed the lat/lng in my URL? This does not want to validate it any way I've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran the URL of an object I published via another app (Endomondo), but which contains GeoPoint data into the debug tool, and this is how they did it. Bear in mind it's an array in this case (it's a path for a cycle activity) so there were actually like 60 of these, but i think a single example would just be:

```
Meta Tag    <meta property="endoapp:route:latitude" content="3x.xxxx" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="endoapp:route:longitude" content="-12x.xxxx" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="endoapp:route:altitude" content="0.01" />
```

Looking at your example, I think maybe the omitted altitude could be the problem?
Endomondo's example uses an array of points in the 'route' field, and one each for start and finish, which are endoapp:start:latitude, endoapp:start:longitude, etc

Comment: Altitude according to the documentation is optional. Also if you look at my meta tags, they look proper, content has the right data embedded and I'm providing location:latitude, location:longitude (foursquare does this also), yet when I debug, I still get the error.

Comment: It's also possible I'm not entering the property right in the Object configuration. I named the property 'location', made it of type 'GeoPoint' and just embedded the code above and made it 'required'

Comment: Is the object data saved properly? If your tags are like those above it should be OK... (It's in the Object, not the Action right?)

Comment: Yes, it was definitely saved, here's a screenshot also: http://cl.ly/452I0j3P2A1S0n060N0C

Answer (score 0):

You should omit what you specified at
property="og:type", i.e. content="my-app"
if so then you should use property="location:latitude" etc (omit "my-app" prefix)